# Problem with filter numbers in slice by range

Tags: arrays, go, range, modulo

I have a problem with the range numbers which I have to filter and enter into the evenNumbers array, but I get compilation errors

```
Make me compile!
//
// I AM NOT DONE
package main_test
 
import (
    "reflect"
    "testing"
)
 
func TestFilterEvenNumbers(t *testing.T) {
    numbers := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
 
    evenNumbers := []int{} // use range to filter even numbers
 
    for _, evenNumbers := range numbers {
        if numbers % 2 {
            evenNumbers = append(numbers)
        }

    }
 
    if !reflect.DeepEqual(evenNumbers, []int{2, 4, 6, 8, 10}) {
        t.Errorf("evenNumbers does not contain all the required even 
        numbers, got %v", evenNumbers)
    }
}
```

Check the output below

```
# command-line-arguments_test [command-line-arguments.test]
exercises/range/range3/main_test.go:18:22: cannot convert 2 (untyped int constant) to []int
exercises/range/range3/main_test.go:19:27: cannot use append(numbers) (value of type []int) as type int in assignment
FAIL    command-line-arguments [build failed]
FAIL
```

Comment: Please do the whole Tour of Go first.

Answer (score 1):

This code is totally wrong, you are using arrays instead of array
elements and don't check % condition correctly. The loop should be:

```
for _, number := range numbers {
    if number%2 == 0 {
        evenNumbers = append(evenNumbers, number)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , Can i get short repsonse how it works because i dont understand this

Comment: I'd suggest you go through [A Tour of Go](https://go.dev/tour/welcome/1)

Comment: I read this but still complicated with some exercise

Comment: `range` for example is explained here https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/16

Comment: @M200020947568: what part don't you understand?

Comment: Why evenNumber was wrong but number in for is working

Comment: `evenNumbers` (there's no `evenNumber` in your code) is _array_ - a group of integers but you have to use only one integer with % operator.